# Is every Singular matrix, nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We say that for a nilpotent matrix
$$ A^p=0 \implies det(A) = 0 $$
So can we say, if $$det(A) = 0$$ then $$A^p=0, \text{ for some p } \in \mathbb{N} $$ and is there a way to determine p other than rigorous trial and error?

Answer (score 7):

The singular matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: Answers my question. 

Comment: @ArchitJain Often, questions have very simple counterexamples that answer them. Learning to find them is an essential mathematical skill!

Comment: Yeah. I guess it takes some time..

Comment: Adding to the answer a bit, a matrix is nilpotent if and only if zero is its only eigenvalue, so even if we restrict to singular matrices, there are still very few nilpotents. If $A$ is an $n \times n$ nilpotent then you always have $A^n=0$. To determine the smallest power you need to take you can look at the Jordan decomposition of the nilpotent. The power you need to take is equal to the size of the largest Jordan block.

Answer (score 0):

We can say that Nilpotent matrices are a subset of singular matrices.
That is, 
All nilpotent matrices are singular. 
But, 
NOT all singular matrices are nilpotent.